# Apache Camel JDBC Insert

Tags: java, apache-camel, esb

I am going through Apache Camel and want to insert data to DB.
My database is SqlServer.
Apache Camel Version is 2.14.1

This is what I tried till now,

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.impl.SimpleRegistry;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;

public class file2DB {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TestDB";

        DataSource datasource = setupDataSource(url);
        SimpleRegistry simpleregistry = new SimpleRegistry();
        simpleregistry.put("DataSource", datasource);
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(simpleregistry);
        context.addRoutes(new file2DB().new MyRouteBuilder());

        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        context.stop();
    }

    class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            try {

                from("direct:myTable")
                .setBody(constant("INSERT INTO employee1(empId,payrollId) VALUES('1234','4567')")) 
                .to("jdbc:DataSource");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
    private static DataSource setupDataSource(String url){
        BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        basicDataSource.setUsername("sa");
        basicDataSource.setPassword("*****");
        basicDataSource.setUrl(url);
        return basicDataSource;
    }

}
```

I checked the Datasource connection using below code and I am getting the result, So there is no issue with connection it seems.

```
        Connection con=null;
        try {
            con = basicDataSource.getConnection();
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from employee1");

            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am not getting any error also data is not getting inserted in table.
I also tried "SELECT" query that is also not working.

I tried Logger and it give me many errors in logs No class defn found twitter etc, which I am not at all using and I think my error is not relevant to that.

Any help.

Comment: There should be some errors/exceptions on the server terminal, when something abnormal happens - when something is not getting inserted into or being retrieved from the associated database. Don't you get anything on the server log - the stack-trace, when you attempt to insert into or retrieve from the database?

Comment: if there is error on server end then I think what I tried testing datasource a basic select query that should also fail right?

Comment: I tried on MySQL as well, same problem persist there. I am missing something in camel api seems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to trigger the Camel route. You use `from("direct:myTable")` and that does not do anything out of the box. You need to either send a message to this endpoint, or change it to a timer or something that triggers a new message.

To send a message use the `ProducerTemplate` which you can find information about here

- http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html
- http://camel.apache.org/walk-through-an-example.html